# XML Reading with Attributes in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I am trying to parse the XML which have multiple nodes with different tags.

The code errors out with Exception as null at line:

```java
System.out.println("Revenue Value : " +    element.getElementsByTagName("ISREVENUE").item(0).getTextContent()).
```

I am unable to parse the attribute to get its value like Group Name "Administration Expenses", its child tags `ISREVENUE` is `"Yes"`, `MASTERID` is `166`, for all the nodes

Expecting output

```
Name (Group) : "Administration Expenses"
Revenue Value : "Yes"
MasterID Value : 166
```

for all the nodes in the xml

Below is the XML Content

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <STATUS>1</STATUS>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <CMPINFO>
                <EXCISEDUTYCLASSIFICATION>0</EXCISEDUTYCLASSIFICATION>
                <SERIALNUMBER>0</SERIALNUMBER>
                <ADJUSTMENTCLASSIFICATION>0</ADJUSTMENTCLASSIFICATION>
                <INCOMETAXSLAB>0</INCOMETAXSLAB>
                <INCOMETAXCLASSIFICATION>0</INCOMETAXCLASSIFICATION>
                <LBTCLASSIFICATION>0</LBTCLASSIFICATION>
                <TAXUNIT>0</TAXUNIT>
                <RETURNMASTER>0</RETURNMASTER>
                <VOUCHER>0</VOUCHER>
            </CMPINFO>
        </DESC>
        <DATA>
            <COLLECTION ISMSTDEPTYPE="Yes" MSTDEPTYPE="4">
                <GROUP NAME="Administration Expenses" RESERVEDNAME="">
                    <ISDELETED TYPE="Logical"></ISDELETED>
                    <ISREVENUE TYPE="Logical">Yes</ISREVENUE>
                    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE TYPE="Logical">Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                    <MASTERID TYPE="Number"> 166</MASTERID>
                </GROUP>
                <GROUP NAME="Bank Accounts" RESERVEDNAME="Bank Accounts">
                    <ISDELETED TYPE="Logical"></ISDELETED>
                    <ISREVENUE TYPE="Logical">No</ISREVENUE>
                    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE TYPE="Logical">Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                    <MASTERID TYPE="Number"> 22</MASTERID>
                </GROUP>
                <GROUP NAME="Bank OD A/c" RESERVEDNAME="Bank OD A/c">
                    <ISDELETED TYPE="Logical"></ISDELETED>
                    <ISREVENUE TYPE="Logical">No</ISREVENUE>
                    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE TYPE="Logical">No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                    <MASTERID TYPE="Number"> 11</MASTERID>
                </GROUP>
            </COLLECTION>
        </DATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Below is the code

```java
try {
    File xmlFile = new File("C:/Srinivas/NewData.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = (Document) builder.parse(xmlFile);

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("GROUP");
    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            String name = element.getAttribute("Name");
            System.out.println("Revenue Value : " +    element.getElementsByTagName("ISREVENUE").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Deemed Value : " + element.getElementsByTagName("ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("completed");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior? Do have "completed" but nothing on screen? An error message?

Comment: "completed" is just for verifying the process is completed, while parsing the node elements it errors out at element.getElementsByTagName("ISREVENUE").item(0).getTextContent(). The XM provided is just a sample, which might have 500 nodes of groups which is provided by external system

Comment: You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469869/xml-reading-with-attributes-in-java#comment134835613_76469869): _it errors out at_ Pardon me, but I could not find details of that error in your question. Perhaps you can [edit] your question and post the error details?

Comment: Yes, like @Abra ask, what's the error you're facing? Is it an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? Something else? Can you paste some logs? It would be the best.

Comment: This was my first post, so Sorry for providing less information. Below is the error in StackTrace "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array." with exception as NullPointerException

Comment: I copied both the XML and the code in your question and the code ran without error. Add the following line to your `catch` block: `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Thanks  Marc Le Bihan & Abra for looking into the issue and spending some time. I have got the needed solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not looping to the child nodes to get the needed values.

Below is the code which had solved the problem.

```
try {

    File xmlFile = new File("C:/Srinivas/NewData.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = (Document) builder.parse(xmlFile);

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("GROUP");
    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {              
        Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + " -- " + node.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());                    
            NodeList childNodes =  node.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0; i< childNodes.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
                if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    System.out.println(childNode.getNodeName() + " -- " + childNode.getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
    System.out.println("completed");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

My desired output is below

```
GROUP -- Administration Expenses
ISDELETED -- 
ISREVENUE -- Yes
ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE -- Yes
MASTERID --  166
---------------------------------------
GROUP -- Bank Accounts
ISDELETED -- 
ISREVENUE -- No
ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE -- Yes
MASTERID --  22
---------------------------------------
GROUP -- Bank OD A/c
ISDELETED -- 
ISREVENUE -- No
ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE -- No
MASTERID --  11
---------------------------------------
completed
```